# I would like to create a fixed Appbar for all my screens

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am trying to use the same Appbar for all my screens, but I don't want to add the same code many times, so I thought about creating the class MyAppbar that would have my default Appbar, so that I could use it in my screens without repeating the same code, but I don't know what I am missing, because it is giving me the following error:

> The method 'Appbar' isn't defined for the class 'MyAppbar'. Try
>   correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a
>   method named 'Appbar'.

This is my code:

```
class MyAppbar extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Appbar(
        centerTitle: true,
        title: Center(
            child: Text("Title", style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'theboldfont'))),
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
              icon: Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.bell),
              onPressed: () {
              }),
          IconButton(
              icon: CircleAvatar(
                  radius: 15,
                  backgroundImage: AssetImage("images/example.png")),
              onPressed: () {}),
        ]);
  }
}
```

Can anyone help me with this error?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

you have a syntax error I believe. It's `AppBar`, not `Appbar`.